# If $f,g$ differ at only a finite number of points, then their lower Riemann integrals equate (proof verification).

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

So the statement we are tasked with proving is as follows

> If $f,g\in\mathbb{B}[a,b]$ are such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for only a finite number of points, $x\in[a,b]$, then
>   $$
> \underline{\int_a^b}f~dx=\underline{\int_a^b}g~dx~~~\mathrm{and}~~~\overline{\int_a^b}f~dx=\overline{\int_a^b}g~dx
> $$
>   And, in particular, $f\in\mathbb{R}[a,b]\iff g\in\mathbb{R}[a,b]$

Now, I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160282/proving-that-if-f-g-differ-at-a-finite-number-of-points-then-the-lower-riemann) post, and used the idea provided in the answer to prove the theorem for myself. I found, however, that this is one such proof where, if you're not meticulous, it'll come back to haunt you. Here is my attempt.

We start by letting $\langle P_n\rangle$ be a limiting sequence of partitions, $P_n\in\mathcal{P}[a,b]$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, of the interval $[a,b]$. Suppose also that $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\cdots,\gamma_k\in[a,b]$ are the values in $[a,b]$ at which $f(x)\neq g(x)$. Suppose, in addition, that $\gamma_1<\gamma_2<\cdots<\gamma_k$. Define now
$$
Q=\min_{1\leq i\leq k}(\gamma_i-\gamma_{i-1})
$$
Now we note that, since $\langle P_n\rangle$ is a limiting sequence, we know that $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N\implies ||P_n||<Q$. Suppose therefore that $n>N$, and hence consider now the expression $\mathcal{L}(f,P_n)-\mathcal{L}(g,P_n)$. We note that any interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, $x_{i-1},x_i\in P_n$, contains at most one value $\gamma\in\lbrace\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\cdots,\gamma_k\rbrace$ (since $||P_n||<Q$). Therefore, if we suppose that each $\gamma_j$ is contained in $[x_{j-1},x_j]$, for some $x_{j-1},x_j\in P_n$, then we have that, if
$$
m_i=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)~~~\mathrm{and}~~~w_i=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}g(x)
$$
then $m_j-w_j=\min\lbrace0,f(\gamma_j)-g(\gamma_j)\rbrace$, $1\leq j\leq k$. Consequently, we have that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}(f,P_n)-\mathcal{L}(g,P_n) & =\sum_{j=1}^k\min\lbrace0,f(\gamma_j)-g(\gamma_j)\rbrace(x_j-x_{j-1}) \\
& \leq\sum_{j=1}^k\min\lbrace0,f(\gamma_j)-g(\gamma_j)\rbrace||P_n|| \\
& =||P_n||\sum_{j=1}^k\min\lbrace0,f(\gamma_j)-g(\gamma_j)\rbrace \\
& \to0\sum_{j=1}^k\min\lbrace0,f(\gamma_j)-g(\gamma_j)\rbrace \\
& =0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
That is, $\mathcal{L}(f,P_n)-\mathcal{L}(g,P_n)\to0$, as $n\to\infty$. Consequently, we have that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\mathcal{L}(f,P_n)-\mathcal{L}(g,P_n)) & =0 \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{L}(f,P_n)-\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{L}(g,P_n) & =0 \\
\underline{\int_a^b}f(x)~dx-\underline{\int_a^b}g(x)~dx & =0 \\
\underline{\int_a^b}f(x)~dx & =\underline{\int_a^b}g(x)~dx \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
As required for the first part. For our purposes, this completes the proof. It should be noted that the second half of the proof is very similar.

My main concern with this proof is style. I think it reads rather poorly, and so if anyone can provide me with some stylistic tips, I would greatly appreciate it. Of course, if the proof lacks validity, please do also point this out to me. Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Comment: I understand that you are being taught integration in this manner, but there is a much more general result from elementary properties of the Lebesgue integral. If a Borel set $E$ has Lebesgue measure zero, and two functions $f$ and $g$ differ only on $E$, we say that $f=g$ almost everywhere, and for any Borel set $F$, $\int_F f\ \mathsf d m = \int_F g\ \mathsf dm$, where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure. Note that any countably infinite set of real numbers has Lebesgue measure zero, which is a much stronger result than showing that differing at a finite set of points does not change the integral.